# Loss not converging in visual question answering with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to train a neural network for visual question answering  but the loss keeps diverging.
Basic hyperparameters modifications gave no results and i've tried different models too with no result. Here is a model i used:

```
word2vec_dim             =      30
num_hidden_nodes_mlp     =     1024
num_hidden_nodes_lstm    =      30
num_layers_lstm          =        2
dropout                  =       0.3
activation_mlp           =     'tanh'
num_epochs = 1

image_model = Sequential()
image_model.add(Reshape(input_shape = (320,480,4), target_shape=(320,480,4)))
image_model.add(Conv2D(4,(3,1)))
image_model.add(Conv2D(4,(1,3)))
image_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
image_model.add(Conv2D(4,(3,1)))
image_model.add(Conv2D(4,(1,3)))
image_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
image_model.add(Conv2D(4,(3,1)))
image_model.add(Conv2D(4,(1,3)))
image_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
image_model.add(Conv2D(4,(3,1)))
image_model.add(Conv2D(4,(1,3)))
image_model.add(Flatten())
image_model.add(Dense(num_hidden_nodes_lstm, activation='relu'))

model1 = Model(inputs = image_model.input, outputs = image_model.output)
model1.summary()


language_model = Sequential()
language_model.add(Embedding(len(unique_words)+1, word2vec_dim, input_length=max_lenght))
language_model.add(LSTM(units=num_hidden_nodes_lstm, 
                        return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, word2vec_dim)))

for i in range(num_layers_lstm-2):
    language_model.add(LSTM(units=num_hidden_nodes_lstm, return_sequences=True))
language_model.add(LSTM(units=num_hidden_nodes_lstm, return_sequences=False))

model2 = Model(language_model.input, language_model.output)
model2.summary()

combined = concatenate([image_model.output, language_model.output])
model = Dense(512, activation="tanh", kernel_initializer="uniform")(combined)
#model = Activation('tanh')(model)
model = Dropout(0.3)(model)

model = Dense(512, activation="tanh", kernel_initializer="uniform")(model)
#model = Activation('tanh')(model)
#model = Dropout(0.5)(model)

#model = Dense(1024, activation="tanh", kernel_initializer="uniform")(model)
#model = Activation('tanh')(model)
#model = Dropout(0.5)(model)

model = Dense(13, activation="softmax")(model)


model = Model(inputs=[image_model.input, language_model.input], outputs=model)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.summary()
```

Here instead the training code. The dataset was split 80/20, batch size 64, epochs are low but since the dataset is big (3k batches), the loss explode before even getting to 10% of a single one.
words target class is one hot encoded and the question encoding is done with a one to one dictionary correspondence (using a dictyonary with every word since there are not many), leaving 0 as padding value. I have ingnored commas, question marks etc. tough.

```
train_gen=image_generator(batch_size=batch_size)
eval_gen=evaluation_generator(batch_size=batch_size)
model.fit(x=train_gen, epochs=2, verbose=1, validation_data=eval_gen, steps_per_epoch=training_batches ,validation_steps=evaluation_batches, shuffle=True, max_queue_size=10, callbacks=[save])
```

I also get this warning message

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/indexed_slices.py:433: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "

Epoch 1/2
 522/3243 [===>..........................] - ETA: 33:05 - loss: 2825421622922535501824.0000
```

I observed that the model would answer to all the question with the same class(I immagine it to be the cause of the diverging loss).

where image_generator is defined:

```
def my_hash (word):
        for x in range(dictionary_lenght-1):
            if word==unique_words[x]:
                return (x+1)
        print("Error, word not in the vocabulary")
def pad(sequence, lenght, value=0):
    for x in range(len(sequence), lenght):
        sequence.append(value)
    return sequence

def image_generator(batch_size = 32):
    zeros=[0]*13
    while True:
        for x2 in range(training_batches):# Select files (paths/indices) for the batch
            input_img_batch = []
            input_question_batch = []
            output_batch = [] 
            img_name=""
            for x in range(batch_size):
                temp=[]
                img_name=training_data["questions"][x+x2*batch_size]["image_filename"]
                question=training_data["questions"][x+x2*batch_size]["question"].replace("?","")

                question=hashing_trick(question, dictionary_lenght,hash_function=my_hash)

                question=pad(question, max_lenght)
                img = Image.open("/kaggle/input/ann-and-dl-vqa/dataset_vqa/train/" + img_name , 'r')
                img=img.resize([img_width, img_height])
                img=np.asarray(img)#execute the same process as before but the corrispective mask

                img=img/255
                input_img_batch.append(img)
                input_question_batch.append(question)
                dummy=zeros
                dummy[encode_answer(training_data["questions"][x+x2*batch_size]["answer"])]=1
                output_batch.append(dummy)

            # Return a tuple of (input,output) to feed the network
            batch_x1 = np.array( input_img_batch )
            batch_x2 = np.array( input_question_batch )
            batch_y = np.array( output_batch )

            yield( [batch_x1, batch_x2], batch_y )
```

Comment: Did you try to increase the number of filters in the convolutional layers? 4 filters seem way too few filters: try 16,32,64,128. or even 32,64,128,256 for all levels of convolution,.

Comment: I tried it but it still diverges

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
There was an issue in the image_generator.
The vector zero somehow changed value and became equal to dummy(instead of the other way) and messed with the  prediction target.